# Django Admin - 404 only for a particular model list view

Tags: django, django-admin

Given these models:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="collections", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
  url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
  collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this admin.py

```
class CollectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Collection, CollectionAdmin)

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

Does anyone know why I can't see the Collection List in admin? I see it in the sidebar, but when I click on it I get a 404.
I should mention that if I type the address for the change view it works, it's just the list view that doesn't work.

My patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('profile/',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="accounts/profile.html"),
        name="profile",
    ),
    path('collections/add/',
        CreateCollectionView.as_view(),
        name="create_collection"
    ),
    path('collections/<int:collection_id>/',
        CollectionDetailView.as_view(),
        name="collection_detail"
    )
]
```

I created and ran all my migrations.

What is even weirder is that I see the Collection list in the ForeignKey field when editing an Item.

[image: Modifying Item]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I'll leave my question up in case that someone else ends up in this corner case.

Before I worked on this project I had opened an older one that used translations, somehow the browser was redirecting from `admin/gear/collection` to `de/admin/gear/collection`. Cleared the browser Cache and Cookies and it works